# Show overlay id using mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Thanks to a really helpful user on this website (whose name I do not know, but I wish to thank and credit him!), I got the following tip on how to store area elements in an array so that when I mouse over a coordinate, I could display all of the overlay id's of the area elements that existed at that coordinate (even if the area elements were not at the same z-level):

I'm just stuck on one thing- once I have gathered all the elements that exist at the coordinate in the hoveredElements array, how do I show their overlay ids?

EDIT:
Here is an example of the full code (the overlay still does not display when I mouse over)

The file test.txt contains:

`cscCSL1A15 700 359 905 318
cscCSL1A14 794 400 905 318`

I use the maphilight plugin available online, and blanketaphi.png is the plot I use as a background.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Detector Elements</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="Demo_imagemap_highlight_files/jquery-1.js"></script>

<!-- add maphilight plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="Demo_imagemap_highlight_files/jquery_002.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
<div class="map" 
style='display: block; background: transparent 
url("Demo_imagemap_highlight_files/blanketaphi.png") 
repeat scroll 0% 0%; position: relative; padding: 0px; width: 1037px; 
height: 557px;'>
<canvas width="1037" height="557" style="width: 1037px; height: 557px; 
position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px none; 
opacity: 1;"></canvas>

<img style="opacity: 0; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding: 0px; 
border: 0px none;" src="Demo_imagemap_highlight_files/blanketaphi.png" 
alt="foo" class="map maphilighted" usemap="#demo" height="557" width="1037" 
border="0" />
</div>
</div>

<map name="demo" id="demo"></map>

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
var f = (function(){ 
  var xhr = [];
  var files = [ "test.txt"];
  for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    (function (i){ 
      xhr[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr[i].open("GET", files[i], true);
      xhr[i].onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr[i].readyState == 4 && xhr[i].status == 200) { 
          // get text contents
          j=20000*i + 50000;
          var coords = xhr[i].responseText.split("\n");
          coords = coords.filter(Boolean) //prevents extra rect with 0 coords
          coords.forEach(function(coord) { 
            var area = document.createElement("area");
            var att = document.createAttribute("data-maphilight"); 
            if (i == 0) { //green
              att.value = '{"strokeColor":"000000","strokeWidth":2,' + 
                  '"fillColor":"009900","fillOpacity":0.5}';
            }
            area.setAttributeNode(att);
            area.id = "r"+j;
            area.shape = "rect";
            area.coords = coord.substring(10,coord.length).trim()
            .replace(/ +/g,","); // replaces spaces in txt file with commas
            area.href = "#";
            area.alt = "r"+j;
            // create overlay with first term in string
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.id ="overlayr"+j;
            div.innerHTML = coord.substring(0,10);
            div.style.display = "none";
            //increase j
            j++;

            // get map element
            document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(area);
            document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(div);
          });
          $('.map').maphilight(); 
          //display overlay ids by mousing over
          var elementPositions = [];
          var hoveredElements = [];

          if($('#demo')) { 
            $('#demo area').each(function() {
              var offset = $(this).offset();

              var top = offset.top;
              var left = offset.left;

              var bottom = $(window).height() - top - $(this).height();
              var right = $(window).width() - left - $(this).width();

              elementPositions.push({ 
                element: $(this), 
                top: top, 
                bottom: bottom, 
                left: left, 
                right: right 
              });
              //alert(top + "," + left + "," + right + "," + bottom);
            }); 
            $("body").mousemove(function(e) {
              hoveredElements = [];

              var yPosition = e.pageX;
              var xPosition = e.pageY;


              for (var i = 0; i < elementPositions.length; i++) { 
                if (xPosition >= elementPositions[i].left && 
                xPosition <= elementPositions[i].right &&
                yPosition >= elementPositions[i].top &&
                yPosition <= elementPositions[i].bottom) {
                  // The mouse is within the element's boundaries
                  $("#hovers").append(elementPositions[i].element); 
                } 
              } 

              for (var i = 0; i < hoveredElements.length; i++) { 
                // The element as a jQuery object
                var elem = hoveredElements[i];
                var id = hoveredElements[i].attr('id');
                $('#overlay'+id).show();
              }
            });
          }; 
        } 
      }; 
      xhr[i].send();
    })(i); 
  } 
})();
};
</script>
```

Comment: Try ' var id = this.id;   $('div').mouseenter(function() {
            $('#overlay'+id).show();
        });'

Comment: Thank you Ram that is another great suggestion- but still nothing displays. Maybe you have an idea of how I could find out what is in hoveredElements at a given time, that way I could have some idea of what I expect to see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just something like this:

```
var elementPositions = [];
var hoveredElements = [];

if($('#demo')) { 
      $('#demo area').each(function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();

        var top = offset.top;
        var left = offset.left;

        var bottom = $(window).height() - top - $(this).height();
        var right = $(window).width() - left - $(this).width();

        elementPositions.push({ element: $(this), top: top, bottom: bottom, left: left, right: right });
      //alert(top + "," + left + "," + right + "," + bottom);
      }); 

      $("body").mousemove(function(e) {
        hoveredElements = [];

        var yPosition = e.pageX;
        var xPosition = e.pageY;


        for (var i = 0; i < elementPositions.length; i++) { 
          if (xPosition >= elementPositions[i].left && 
          xPosition <= elementPositions[i].right &&
          yPosition >= elementPositions[i].top &&
          yPosition <= elementPositions[i].bottom) {
        // The mouse is within the element's boundaries
                hoveredElements.push(elementPositions[i].element);
                $("#hovers").append(elementPositions[i].element); 
                 } 
        } //end of for loop over all elements

       console.log(hoveredElements);

        for (var i = 0; hoveredElements.length; i++)
        { //for loop over all hovered elements
          // The element as a jQuery object
          var elem = hoveredElements[i];
          var id = hoveredElements[i].attr('id');
          console.log(id);
          $('#overlay'+id).show();
          // Do stuff to that jQuery element:
          //??? something like elem.show();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks that is a great suggestion- but still nothing displays. Maybe you have an idea of how I could find out what is in hoveredElements at a given time, that way I could have some idea of what I expect to see...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise that the `hoveredElements` array wasn't actually having anything added to it. I've updated the code to do so, please try that now.

Comment: Thank you again, but still no dice. Do you have suggestions on how I could debug the problem? Debugger finds nothing and the code runs fine, but nothing displays.

Comment: I've added two log calls to the code. The first one will spit out the hoveredElements array and the second will spit out the id of any element it finds in the array.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to put together a basic example of this so we can look at it?

Comment: Ok, a couple of things were going wrong with your code, please see here: https://plnkr.co/edit/vKvNYEuHD5uj9fqIYWsZ?p=preview.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You've got a lot of stuff here that doesn't make sense to me but here's what I can gather so far. 
Your areas need to be in a container called `demo area`. Not sure how the space in the ID works so in my case I switched it to `demoarea`. Also somewhere in the page, there has to be another element called `demo` for anything to even happen.

Once that's done, the script loads `demoarea` into the elementPositions array. Judging from your description that's not what you want to do, you probably want to load all the elements inside `demoarea`into the array. So the first change is

```
$('#demo area').each(function() {
```

Becomes

```
$('#demoarea').children().each(function() {
```

Now what becomes confusing to me is that this script for whatever reason decides that you need to have another element called `hover` so it can move the element out of `demoarea` into `hover` when you mouse over it. If that is what you want, then you can do your show trick with some simple CSS.

```
<div style="display:none" id="overlayr6064"> Example Overlay ID name </div>
```

Becomes

```
<div id="overlayr6064"> Example Overlay ID name </div>
```

And then you add:

```
<style>
    #demoarea div {
        display: none;
    }
    #hover div {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

Assuming that is not what you wanted, what @liamEgan did to add the elements to the `hoveredElements` array is good, but you have an infinite loop here

```
for (var i = 0; hoveredElements.length; i++)
```

it should be

```
for (var i = 0; i < hoveredElements.length; i++)
```

Then the rest works... except one last thing, you want to load these listeners to your script when the page loads in a document ready method.

So in all it looks a bit like:

```js
//display overlay ids by mousing over (my map is called 'demo')
var elementPositions = [];
var hoveredElements = [];

if($('#demo')) { 
  $('#demoarea').children().each(function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();

    var top = offset.top;
    var left = offset.left;

    var bottom = $(window).height() - top - $(this).height();
    var right = $(window).width() - left - $(this).width();

    elementPositions.push({ element: $(this), top: top, bottom: bottom, left: left, right: right });
  }); 
  console.log('After Scanning demoarea elementPositions looks like:')
  console.log(elementPositions);
  
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").mousemove(function(e) {
      hoveredElements = [];

      var yPosition = e.pageX;
      var xPosition = e.pageY;


      for (var i = 0; i < elementPositions.length; i++) { 
        if (xPosition >= elementPositions[i].left && 
            xPosition <= elementPositions[i].right &&
            yPosition >= elementPositions[i].top &&
            yPosition <= elementPositions[i].bottom) {
          // The mouse is within the element's boundaries
          if (typeof elementPositions[i].element != "undefined") {
            hoveredElements.push(elementPositions[i].element);
            $("#hovers").append(elementPositions[i].element); 
          }
        } 
      } //end of for loop over all elements

      for (var i = 0; i < hoveredElements.length; i++) { //for loop over all hovered elements
        // The element as a jQuery object
        console.log(hoveredElements[i]);
        if (typeof hoveredElements[i] != "undefined") {
          var elem = hoveredElements[i];
          var id = elem.attr('id');
          $('#overlay'+id).show();
        }
        // Do stuff to that jQuery element:
        //??? something like elem.show();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```css
#demoarea {
  border: 2px blue dotted;
}
/* Border added so I can see where to mouse over */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div id="demoarea">
    <area shape="rect" coords="431,499,458,491" href="#" id="r6064" alt="r6064">
    <div style="display:none" id="overlayr6064"> Example Overlay ID name </div>
  </div>
  <div id="hovers">
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: sorry I added the undefined tests while fixing this because of the infinite loop but I think they're not really needed. Still nice to have though. Also since the area also gets moved into the hover area this script does try to show an element called `overlayoverlayr6064r6064` which fortunately doesn't exist. But ya, again, probably not what you had in mind.

Comment: Just going to put this out there and say I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve with all this, it'd be easier to show hide stuff when you mouse over the element itself instead of storing it all in an array. I do understand the z-index can be a pain, but some careful planning can solve all that

Comment: Yes, I am just a beginner. I need to see all z layers underneath a coordinate and this seemed like the simplest way. If you have any other suggestions I will gladly take them!

Comment: Everyone's a beginner at some point. I think if you intend to have overlapping layers then this isn't that bad, but you should probably remove that part about the append to `hover` as that could mess with stuff for no reason. Also you can add a selector to the `children` method to get only the `area` elements like `children('area`)` then that'll solve the `overlayoverlayr6064r6064` issue. Best of luck with your app, whatever it maybe

Comment: Thank you! It is working now, thank you for the advice and good luck.